# Linking with warning and then undefined reference

Tags: cmake

I am trying to compile an application with Cmake.

Almost at the end of the state: 100%

I got:

```
/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.5.2/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: warning: libIMGegl.so, needed by /arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/libEGL.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

and then a lot of messages of

```
undefined reference to 'something'
```

Where can I added -rpath or -rpath-link

This is my CMAKE FLAG:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-O2 -mcpu=cortex-a9 -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=softfp -g -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -fpic -mthumb-interwork -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-short-enums -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing ${CMAKE_ARM_LINUX_FLAGS}" CACHE INTERNAL "")
```

Comment: Can you paste your cmake configuration file?

Comment: @Tal, im not familiar with cmake config file yet. it is a big project. any hint where can I find the cmake config file? Thanks

Comment: Try searching for "CMakeLists.txt" or any file that contains "cmake" or "cmake_minimum_required"

Comment: there are many CMakeLists.txt file that also contains cmake. I am searching for cmake_minimum_required